# I have 2 global Variables that get assigned new values multiple time during code run. Would like to record the values in CSV under single column

Tags: c#, excel

I have a program that has 2 variables. Var1 and Var2. Each one gets assigned a new value through out the code during code run, lets say 20 times. at the end of code, I have a csv writing method that exports var1 and var2 output into 2 columns. The issue is that the csv writer method only takes the last iteration of the variables output and puts it in the cells. I want to have it take all output data and append onto new cell below.

```
static void Main()
{
    // Global Variables
    double var1;
    double var2;

    //...some blocks of code do stuff

    Console.WriteLine("Data 1 = " + var1); // output: Data 1 = 3
    Console.WriteLine("Data 1 = " + var2); // output: Data 2 = 10

    //...some blocks of code do stuff
                     
    Console.WriteLine("Data 1 = " + var1); // output: Data 1 = 34
    Console.WriteLine("Data 2 = " + var2); // output: Data 2 = 56
     
    //...some blocks of code do stuff

    Console.WriteLine("Data 1 = " + var1); // output: Data 1 = 37
    Console.WriteLine("Data 1 = " + var2); // output: Data 2 = 0

    //...some blocks of code do stuff
     
    Console.WriteLine("Data 1 = " + var1); // output: Data 1 = 347
    Console.WriteLine("Data 2 = " + var2); // output: Data 2 = 546

    // Writing to CSV class call
    ExcellHandler.Test("fileName", var1.ToString(), var2.ToString());

    // Here I export the 2 variables and drop them into the csv
}
```

The image shows what I want to get. [image: output csv]

Instead of that I get, the last 2 values [347, 546] in the entire csv.

Can someone please help me solve this problem? Thank you for you help :)

Comment: Append the values to the file at the same point where you're doing each pair of Console.WriteLine.  Otherwise, you're only getting the last values of `var1` and `var2`.  Or, store the values of each variable in an object such as a List before the variable value is changed and then write the contents of the List to the file once.

Comment: do you mind giving me an example? Please and thank you for responding.

Answer (score 1):

In the code you posted, you are printing the values to the console, not to the CSV file, so instead of calling

```
Console.WrtileLine();
```

You should be calling

```
ExcellHandler.Test("fileName", var1.ToString(), var2.ToString());
```

Each time you want to write info to the CSV file, and also make sure that the ExcelHandler is adding the content to the file and not overwriting the complete file.

**Edit:**

Example with CSVHelper : codingame.com/playgrounds/5197/writing-csv-files-using-c

```
    using CsvHelper;
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Text;

namespace CSVFile
{
    public class Project
    {
        public string CustomerName;
        public string Title;
        public DateTime Deadline;
    }

    class Program
    {      

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var data = new[]
            {
                new Project { CustomerName = "Big Corp", Title = "CRM updates", Deadline = DateTime.Today.AddDays(-2) },
                new Project { CustomerName = "Imaginary Corp", Title = "Sales system", Deadline = DateTime.Today.AddDays(1) }
            };

            using (var mem = new MemoryStream())
            using (var writer = new StreamWriter(mem))
            using (var csvWriter = new CsvWriter(writer, new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("US-en")))
            {
                csvWriter.WriteField("Customer");
                csvWriter.WriteField("Title");
                csvWriter.WriteField("Deadline");
                csvWriter.NextRecord();

                foreach (var project in data)
                {
                    csvWriter.WriteField(project.CustomerName);
                    csvWriter.WriteField(project.Title);
                    csvWriter.WriteField(project.Deadline);
                    csvWriter.NextRecord();
                }

                writer.Flush();
                var result = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(mem.ToArray());
                Console.WriteLine(result);
                Console.ReadKey();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi @shadowraz, would I have to put this line under each console iteration that happens? would this create new file everything?

Comment: I am using excel interop and not sure how to tell my method to append

Comment: Found this example that uses a NugetPackage that is very recommended when working with CSV files called CsvHelper: https://www.codingame.com/playgrounds/5197/writing-csv-files-using-c

And I tweaked the example a little to make it work on my project, so this is the code, just need to, instead of showing the content of the Csv file to the console, just write it to a location on your computer